# angular unit test for renderer.listen

Tags: angular

how to create test cases for angular in code

```
this.renderer.listen('window','click',(e:Event)=>{

  if(e.target==document.queryselector('.overlay')){

  close()
}

})
}
```

I am using this method in constructor. how to unit test for this in spec.ts file in angular